# Bug in the documentation of the function 'delete' in 'SQLiteDataBase'

Tags: java, android, sqlite

The `delete` function for the `SQLiteDatabase` object is a three arguments function : the table, the "Where" clause and the "Where" args. Unfortunately, in the Android SDK documentation, only the first two parameters are described and there is absolutely nothing about the third one.

Can anyone tell me what the third is supposed to represent? Can the doc be updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

whereArgs are the values to the where clause and , where you use the "?" placeholder in the whereClause, you've to provide the whereArgs

EG:

```
dbhelper.delete(DB_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[] { col })
```

Its essentially for safe querying and prevention of SQL injection when you have parameters with special characters like "=" and what not.
So no bug in the docs, probably the description has been left out because the argument name is self explanatory